# How do you develop skill speaking clearly with confidence

Tags: communication, work-environment

Usually, I speak well.

But sometimes either because of my introverted nature or distractions in my mind, I don't respond to people with a clear voice and confidence and they get confused.

How can I develop the skill to react quickly and speak confidently all the time?

Any reading, trainings, etc. might be useful as well.

Comment: This is probably more suited for the Interpersonal Skills Stack

Comment: Try to repost with a specific workplace situation so we can help you.

Answer (score 5):

There's plenty of public speaking tutorials and books available online and in your local bookstore.

Nothing really beats practice though as a way of boosting your confidence.  And when you're confident about what you're speaking about, this transmits to your audience.

Start off speaking about things you're confident about and go from there.

If you have a dog, speak to it.  If you have a [stuffed toy duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), talk to it.

Practice, practice, practice.

Comment: There are also clubs around set up to allow to practice this skill. Nothing is the same as speaking in front of an actual audience who can give you feedback. Toastmasters is a popular one in my area. See if there is one near you.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue in the past and I still often experience occasions where I feel like what I am saying or doing isn't good enough and lack confidence. Some people have it in their nature and it's something that is difficult to shift.

I've watched Youtube videos, online courses and even spoke with Colleagues and friends. The best thing for me was just putting myself out there and going out of my comfort zone. Seeing myself do the things I never thought i'd be able to really helped motivate me and give me the drive to do it more often.

Focus on what you are trying to say and not how you are going to sound when you say it and do not compare yourself to others as everyone has things they're not good at and people chose to adopt different methods for speaking, presenting or generally just talking to other people.

Take your time and don't be afraid if you mess up and say the wrong thing, correct yourself and continue.

Take regular breaths and don't try and blurt everything out in one go.

I struggle with eye contact, but trying to make eye contact really helps. You know what you feel comfortable with, start with that and over time introduce new methods and try new things and you'll get there.

Edit: I should also add, if you know your topic you are more likely to come across as sounding more confident about it. Don’t try and speak about something you’re not sure about and if you aren’t sure, don’t be afraid to say.